# Knockoutjs Loop array each checkbox control own content hide or show?

Tags: knockout.js

Having an array and loop it to show with a checkbox for each item, and under each item, have some text, default just show all items with unchecked checkboxes. Once click the checkbox, show this item's content, and click next will show next item's content. Usually we will have visible attr on the content  or , but it's cross all, unless we have a specific id or class name matching with selected item's id or class, how should we do it in Knockoutjs?

Comment: Your question is probably being down-voted because the wording and grammar is very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you describe sounds like a row-details type of feature.  In order to provide this, each item needs to be able to specify its own value indicating whether details for that item are visible.

Here's an example of what I mean:

The HTML below displays a list, and for each item in the array, contains a "header" and "details" section:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li>
        <label><span  data-bind="text:header"></span> <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isDetailsVisible" />
        </label>
        <div data-bind="visible: isDetailsVisible">
            <span  data-bind="text:details"></span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The view model below creates two Item entries, each of which provide the isDetailsVisible property:

```
var Item = function(header, details){
    self = this;
    self.header = ko.observable(header);
    self.details = ko.observable(details);
    self.isDetailsVisible = ko.observable(false);
}

var vm = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
        new Item("Apple", "makes great pies"),
        new Item("Grape", "frequently used in wine-making")
        ])
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates:  http://jsfiddle.net/blugrasmaniac/fhRNV/